# Unable to get/write the folder name using FileLeafRef inside my PnP Power shell script

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have this PnP PowerShell script to get the folder name:-

```
PS C:\Users\m> $SiteURL = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/FilePortal"
PS C:\Users\m> $mainfolderUrl = "/sites/FilePortal/Customer Share/Clients"
PS C:\Users\m> $listName = "Customer Share"
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\m> Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\mo> $customerFolders= Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -FolderServerRelativeUrl $mainfolderUrl -PageSize 1  | Where {$_.FieldValues.FileDirRef -eq $mainfolderUrl } | Select-Object id,@{label="Filename";expression={$_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef}},@{label="Fileurl";expression={$_.FieldValues.FileDirRef}},@{label="Modified";expression={$_.FieldValues.Modified}}
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\m> ForEach($customerFolder in $customerFolders)
>> {
>> $customerFolder}

Id Filename Fileurl                                      Modified
-- -------- -------                                      --------
 4 ClientA  /sites/FilePortal/Customer Share/Clients 11/07/2023 23:39:11
 5 ClientB  /sites/FilePortal/Customer Share/Clients 11/07/2023 23:39:16
 6 ClientC  /sites/FilePortal/Customer Share/Clients 11/07/2023 23:39:22
```

but when I tried to only print the foldername , as follow i will get this error `Cannot index into a null array`:-

```
PS C:\Users\mo> $SiteURL = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/FilePortal"
PS C:\Users\m> $mainfolderUrl = "/sites/FilePortal/Customer Share/BGG Clients"
PS C:\Users\m> $listName = "Customer Share"
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\m> Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\m> $customerFolders= Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -FolderServerRelativeUrl $mainfolderUrl -PageSize 1  | Where {$_.FieldValues.FileDirRef -eq $mainfolderUrl } | Select-Object id,@{label="Filename";expression={$_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef}},@{label="Fileurl";expression={$_.FieldValues.FileDirRef}},@{label="Modified";expression={$_.FieldValues.Modified}}
PS C:\Users\m>
PS C:\Users\m> ForEach($customerFolder in $customerFolders)
>> {
>> $customerFolder.FileLeafRef
>> $customerFolder.FieldValues['Filename']  }
InvalidOperation:
Line |
   4 |  $customerFolder.FieldValues['Filename']  }
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot index into a null array.
InvalidOperation:
Line |
   4 |  $customerFolder.FieldValues['Filename']  }
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot index into a null array.
InvalidOperation:
Line |
   4 |  $customerFolder.FieldValues['Filename']  }
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot index into a null array.
```

any advice?
Thanks